# Show Validation in Signature field when field value is false?

Tags: javascript, validation, digital-signature, odoo-10

I have to try to show validation when my signature field is blank. i am use alert message but it's not working like i am click on OK button and also show validation message but it's save form. So any one suggest me how to stop this continue show validation message if my field is blank and i have try to save. 
My code is below :

```
on_save_sign: function(value_) {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.find('> img').remove();
        var signature = self.$el.find(".signature").jSignature("getData",'image');
        var is_empty = signature
            ? self.empty_sign[1] === signature[1]
            : false;
        if (! is_empty && typeof signature !== "undefined" && signature[1]) {
            self.set('value',signature[1]);
        }
        else {
               alert('Signature First');
                self.do_warn(_t("Signature First"));

                           }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code.

```
on_save_sign: function(value_) {
        var self = this;
        this.$el.find('> img').remove();
        var signature = self.$el.find(".signature").jSignature("getData",'image');
        var is_empty = signature
            ? self.empty_sign[1] === signature[1]
            : false;
        if(is_empty){
            self.do_warn("Please enter valid signature.")
        }
        if (! is_empty && typeof signature !== "undefined" && signature[1]) {
            self.set('value',signature[1]);
        }
    },
```

Hope It will help you. If still not working try to use debug assets and reload the page. check your updated code is there by adding console in above conditions.

Have a good day !

Comment: Hello, it's working but  It's show only warning message after save form. i want to still edit mode not save from so any suggest what i can do ?

Comment: In that you need to modify both on_save_sign and save method.

In on_save_sign do something like 

if (empty){
return false
}else{
//set value here
return true
}

NOw in save method you need to do following

save: function() {
            check_sign=this.$el.find('.save_sign').click();
            if(!check_sign){
               return your warnign msg
          }else{
return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
}
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
on_save_sign: function(value_) {
this.$el.find('> img').remove();
var signature = this.$el.find(".signature").jSignature("getData", 'image');
var is_empty = signature
    ? this.empty_sign[1] === signature[1]
    : false;
if (is_empty) {
    this.do_warn("Please enter valid signature.")
}
else {
    this.set('value', signature[1]);
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, it's working but It's show only warning message after save form. i want to still edit mode not save from so any suggest what i can do ?